# SQLiteDirectCursorDriver usage of SelectionArgs or workaround - using placeholders

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

I have a rawQuery string running but SQlite throws this warning :

> SQLiteDirectCursorDriver(1058): Found SQL string that ends in ;

because of quote issues. So I'm trying to use SelectionArgs in a query where I do not have really replacement by values, like this :

```
String query = "SELECT Min(?) as oldest, Max(?) as newest, COUNT(?) as nb_data FROM ? WHERE ? BETWEEN (SELECT Min(?) FROM ?) AND (SELECT Max(?) FROM ?)";
String[] values = new String[] { TS, TS, col_2, table, TS, TS, table, TS, table };
Cursor mCount = database.rawQuery(query, values);
```

I can't get it working, even using fewer SelectionArgs strings (only on the "WHERE" part of the query) as there is not really value replacement requirements but placeholders.

Is there a solution to set this prepared statement (using placeholders rather than using quotes or rewriting the original query) to avoid getting the SQLiteDirectCursorDriver warning ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parameters only for expressions, not for identifiers.

To prevent this warning, just omit the semicolon from the end of your SQL query strings.

Comment: Thx actually this is also where I ended :-).